# ArrayAdapter getView position is not true

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

For my ListView I have this ArrayAdapter

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, uas) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View item = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            if(uas.size() > 0 && tinydb.getInt("selectedUA", 0) == position) {
                item.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }

            return item;
        }
    };
```

Lets say the selectedUA is 3, so it colors the 3rd index green. The problem is that the first index always gets colored too. It seems that the position value or something has a bug. Can anyone help me?

Comment: maybe log or print the tinydb.getInt("selectedUA", 0) value inside the if block to see what it returns exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try resetting the default color for the other rows if the condition is false:

```
 if(uas.size() > 0 && tinydb.getInt("selectedUA", 0) == position) {
       item.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
 } else {
       // e.g.
       item.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
 }
```